# Comparing two columns from one dataset to the same column from another dataset in R

Tags: r

I have two datasets that are almost similar. I want to compare IDs and Birthday from dataset one to IDs and Birthday from the second column to see if the two datasets match.
I did:

```
table(dat1$ID %in% dat2$ID) # there are 7 differences
```

then I did

```
table(dat1$Bday %in% dat2$bday) # they are the same
```

But when I tried

```
 s1 <- dat1[ ! ( (dat1$ID %in% dat2$ID) && (dat1$Bday %in% dat2$Bday) )]
```

all of them are true. But there are 7 who are not in the ID.

Any idea how to compare multiple columns from one dataset to another dataset?

Comment: see this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261937/how-to-compare-two-columns-and-write-the-result-into-a-third-using-r

Comment: Hey Duber - welcome to stack overflow! Its much easier for everyone to help you here when you provide a "minimum working example" of your problem. In your case, that would probably be data for two small dataframes (dat1 and dat2) and exact which differences you are hoping to extract from these two. Then you can use peoples answers to apply to your bigger question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And also, if you can us the ticks (found under the esc key) before and after code samples it is easier to follow the logic of the questions

Comment: I think you should consider element wise and operator `&` instead of `&&`